# I’m trying to realise funds but being asked to pay in commissions to a wallet address before my funds are released, is this normal?

Tags: wallet, withdrawal, escrow

I have made investment and am trying to realise my funds. My account closure process seems complicated and I’m being asked to pay in more funds in the form of BTC to a wallet to cover commissions before my funds are released. I’m reluctant to pay in more funds and am concerned this might be a scam, how do I know?

Is this the normal withdrawal process, to pay more in first?

Comment: This is called [fee advance fraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam).

Comment: This is a scam and your money is already all gone.